# How to connect to database on another server?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
$dbh=mysql_connect('187.0.0.0','abcd','1234') or die(mysql_error());
if($dbh)
{
echo "server connected";
}
$db=mysql_select_db('demo') or die(mysql_error());
if($db)
{
echo "database connected";
}
?>
```

I used this code on another server to check the connectivity but I'm 
    getting an error

> Host 'mail.hosting1001.in' is not allowed to connect to    this MySQL server

Answer (score 2):

The server has to allow remote connections by the user in question. Use the `GRANT` syntax to give your user remote permissions (but limit those permissions to the IP address from which you are making the remote connection, assuming it's a fixed address).

Even better, as feeela suggested in the comments: open a secure tunnel between the machines so that you can connect as if you were connecting to the local machine.

Also, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Nice problem description, but opening the SQL server sounds like a Bad Idea™. A better idea is to create an SSH tunnel from one server to the other and use the DB as if it were a local DB.

Comment: I don't know about the permissions. How can i give this? Will you please explain me in detail?

Comment: @vipin Please see [the documentation for `GRANT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html). For example, you might run the command `GRANT SELECT ON demo.* TO 'abc'@'123.45.67.89' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';`, where `demo` is your database, `abc` is your user, `123.45.67.89` is the IP address of the remote machine, and `mypass` is your password. Again, be careful with this. feeela's point is a good one, and that is the better route.